# Java Call Char Method To Collect Characters Between A to W

Tags: java, methods, char

I am writing a code to display the letters from a to w with only 10 letters per line. My assignment says to call the method  "public static void printChars(char c1, char c2)" but I'm not really sure how to go about calling this method. My code is still *very* messy and I am trying to untangle and understand it based on the example given in my textbook:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CallingTheCharMethods {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Printing all letters between a and w:");
}

final int NUMBER_OF_CHARS = 23;
final int CHARS_PER_LINE = 10;

}

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHARS; i++) {

char ch = public static void printChars(char c1, char c2);

if ((i + 1) % CHARS_PER_LINE == 0)

System.out.println(ch);
else
System.out.print(ch);

}
```

Again, I'm sorry for the messy, stupid code. I'm trying to understand this the best I can.

Answer (score 1):

The idea about having a method like

```
public static void printChars(char c1, char c2)
```

is that it can be called from main with different parameters

e.g.

```
  printChars ('a', 'w');
```

The code in this method would be something like

```
  for (char startChar = c1; startChar <= c2; startChar++) {
       print startChar
  }
```

Now added to this, you are required to make a newline if you have already printed 10, so add a counter

ending up with

```
    int counter = 1;
    for (char startChar = c1; startChar <= c2; startChar++) {
        System.out.print(startChar);
        if (counter++ % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe rename `c1` and  `c2` and `start` into `firstChar` and `lastChar` and `ch`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I agree, but based upon the assignment it should be `c1` and `c2`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for your help! So I'm redoing my code to better work around the tips and information you have provided for me. After displaying the system.out.print "Printing all letters..." part of the code, I do not understand how to go about invoking the printChar method. I coded:  public static void printChars('a', 'w') but I am getting an error. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: To invoke `printChars`  simply call it after `System.out.println("Printing all letters between a and w:");`  like `printChars ('a', 'w');`  - what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class CallingTheCharMethods {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {    // your main method; the first method which is excuted when your run your code
        System.out.println("Printing all letters between a and w:");
        printChars('a', 'w'); //  calling the printChars method with the parameters a and w
    }

    private static void printChars(char c1, char c2) {   // definition of the printChars method : accept two chars c1 and c2 as parameter
       int charsPerLine = 1;
       for (char firstChar = c1; firstChar <= c2; firstChar++,charsPerLine++){               // start from c1 as first charachter and print until c2
           if(charsPerLine%10 == 0){                                                         // count already printed chars and keep the value in the var  charsPerLine
               System.out.println(firstChar);                                               // if charsPerLine equals n*10 start a new line 
           }                                                                                //(println() prints on a new line)
           else{
               System.out.print(firstChar);                                                 // (print() prints on the current line)
           }
       }
     }
    }
```